# Import database table (specific row) based on matching validator

Tags: sql, csv

I have a database running now that has had all data in the "leads column" / "phone number row" removed. I have created an updated csv file that has most of the phone numbers present in addition to the client name, email and address.

How can I import the phone numbers in the phone numbers row based on matching the client name, email or address data, without affected any other columns or rows other than the phone numbers row?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the perfect fit for an SSIS package! (this is assuming you are referring to SQL Server...since you didnt list an RDBMS it is just a guess)

Some SSIS package basics materials:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/155829/SQL-Server-Integration-Services-SSIS-Part-Basics

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms169917(v=sql.110).aspx

http://ssistutorial.blogspot.com/

SSIS is basically an ETL package development tool used with SQL Server that has countless options for moving data around. You would only need on data flow task inside of SSIS to accomplish what you are searching for. I highly recommend reading up on some of the content above and giving it a shot!